# BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::save()

Tags: php, database, laravel, exception, eloquent

```
try{
        if($request->file('foto') != null) //cek apakah ada input foto, ini block jika ada
        {
            $file = $request->file('foto');
            $tujuan_upload = 'foto';
            $file->move($tujuan_upload,$file->getClientOriginalName());

            $user=Teller::find($id_teller);
            $user->name=$request->name;
            $user->email=$request->email;
            $user->foto=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $user->save();

            $user2  = TellerDetail::where('id_login', $id_teller);
            $user2->nip = $request->nip;
            $user2->jenis_kelamin = $request->jenkel;
            $user2->tempat_lahir = $request->tempat;
            $user2->tanggal_lahir = $request->tanggal;
            $user2->no_telp = $request->no_telp;
            $user2->save();
        }

        else{
            $user=Teller::find($id_teller);
            $user->name=$request->name;
            $user->email=$request->email;
            $user->save();

            $user2  = TellerDetail::where('id_login', $id_teller)->first();
            $user2->nip = $request->nip;
            $user2->jenis_kelamin = $request->jenkel;
            $user2->tempat_lahir = $request->tempat;
            $user2->tanggal_lahir = $request->tanggal;
            $user2->no_telp = $request->no_telp;
            $user2->save();
        }
        
        Session::flash('sukses', 'Profil Berhasil Diupdate');
        return redirect()->route('teller.dashboard');
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
      
            // Session::flash('gagal', 'Data tidak valid, pastikan data yang anda masukan benar');
            return $e;

        return back();
    }
```

> BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::save()

I am trying to save the data, there is an image file, the file already moved to destination folder, and my table is updated, so why it throw exception? Please anyone can tell me whats wrong, I can't figure it out.

Comment: `$user2  = TellerDetail::where('id_login', $id_teller);` You missed the `->fist()` on this one. You can't call `->where(...)->save();`, you need `->where(...)->first()->save()`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: sir... thanks, its been 3 hours, you save me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet, the error is in the first line of `$user2`. You forgot to execute the query via `first()` so that you have the `TellerDetail` model instead of the `Builder`

```
$user2  = TellerDetail::where('id_login', $id_teller)->first();
$user2->nip = $request->nip;
$user2->jenis_kelamin = $request->jenkel;
$user2->tempat_lahir = $request->tempat;
$user2->tanggal_lahir = $request->tanggal;
$user2->no_telp = $request->no_telp;
$user2->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss the `first()` method. You can't call the `save()` method on `where` clause. You must call the `first()` method after the `where` clause or use `find()` instead of `where()`.

example:

```
$user=Teller::find($id_teller)->first();
$user2  = TellerDetail::where('id_login', $id_teller)->first();
```